# How to return mix/multiple data in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the page views count for a page from analytics data with BigQuery (Started just yesterday).
Both work individually.

If I run the first query,

```
SELECT count(1) AS views, event_date AS date from `project-id.analytics_number.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) as param1 where event_name = 'page_view' AND param1.value.string_value='/[page]' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  AND
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY event_date ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

It gives me the data as follows:

```
[
  {
    "views": "6",
    "date": "20210101"
  },
  {
    "views": "55",
    "date": "20210102"
  },
  {
    "views": "3",
    "date": "20210103"
  },
  {
    "views": "12",
    "date": "20210104"
  },
  {
    "views": "5",
    "date": "20210105"
  }
]
```

Then if I try to get the total count of all the views using:

```
 SELECT count(*) as count from `project-id.analytics_number.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) 
   as param1 where event_name = 'page_view' AND param1.value.string_value='/[page]'
```

This gives me:

```
[
  {
    "count": "81"
  }
]
```

This working as I want. Now I am trying to get the data at the same time. In one query, is that something possible?

I was trying this, but not working.

```
with first as (
  SELECT count(1) AS views, event_date AS date from `project-id.analytics_number.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) as param1 where event_name = 'page_view' AND param1.value.string_value='/[page]' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  AND
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY event_date ORDER BY event_date ASC
),
second as (
    SELECT count(*) as count from `project-id.analytics_number.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) 
   as param1 where event_name = 'page_view' AND param1.value.string_value='/[page]'
)
select * from second
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for better performance

```
with first as (
  SELECT count(1) AS views, event_date AS date from `project-id.analytics_number.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) as param1 where event_name = 'page_view' AND param1.value.string_value='/[page]' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  AND
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY event_date ORDER BY event_date ASC
)
select views, date from (
select views, date from first
union all
select sum(views) as views, NULL as date from first
) order by date asc
```

Comment: `Syntax error: Trailing comma after the WITH clause before the SELECT clause is not allowed at [6:1]`
Sorry, I would have debugged, but unfortunately, I am not experienced enough. :(

Comment: ok, removed comma for with, it should work

Comment: One last thing, the dates are not in order, I see `ORDER BY event_date ASC` but is it not working? Also the total count coming at the first element or last of the array. Is there a way we can make it fixed? I don't mind even if it is in a different object.
Or that's something we cant do?

Comment: Thanks a ton. Sorry for the trouble too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` to combine them:

```
SELECT count(*) AS views, event_date AS date 
FROM `project-id.analytics_number.events_*` CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(event_params) as param1 
WHERE event_name = 'page_view' AND 
      param1.value.string_value='/[page]' AND
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND
                            FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY event_date 
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) as count, NULL 
FROM `project-id.analytics_number.events_*` CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(event_params) as param1 
WHERE event_name = 'page_view' AND 
      param1.value.string_value='/[page]'
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you so much.
Just a QQ, I see sometimes the total count coming at the first element or last of the array. Is there a way we can make it fixed? I don't mind even if it is in a different object.

Comment: @SubhenduKundu . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.  I mean, you can use `with offset` to get the array index, but then you need to figure out which one you want.

Comment: What about the `ORDER BY event_date ASC`, that is not working. :(